# Passing Java arguments to bundle under Equinox OSGI framework?

Tags: osgi, command-line-arguments

I our application we have several bundles that are running by the Equinox OSGI framework (with Tomcat).

Currently we are passing the application configuration mostly by Java system properties.
This properties are shared across all bundles and all of them can access to the properties value.

We are trying to find other option to pass them so only a specific bundle could access a specific property.

Is there a way to do it by a Java arguments?
How can i pass a java argument to a specific bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the Config Admin service, it is designed for this use case, providing specific bundles with configuration information. Apache Felix File Install provides a convenient mechanism to supply configuration data through property files. Probably Equinox has something similar, but felix file install should run on Equinox.